# jquery mobile assign data to listview with list divider

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

here is the code i try to assign a json to a listview

```
$.each(result, function(i, item) {
    //alert(item);
    if (item.class == "forumInfo" ) {
          $("#pages_list").append($("<li></li>",{"html":"<a href='#page_node_view' id='" + item.text + "' class='page_node_pages_list_title'>" + item.text + "</a>"}));
    }
    if (item.class == "group") {
          $("#pages_list").append($("<li data-role='list-divider' role='heading'></li>",{"html": item.text}));
    }
});
```

The list divider can't show the text, what is the problem?

Comment: $("#pages_list").append($("<li></li>",{"data-role": "list-divider", "html": item.text}));

problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the same thing but without the JSON objects

```
$.each(result, function(i, item) {
    //alert(item);
    if (item.class == "forumInfo" ) {
          var list_item = $("<li></li>");
          list_item.html("<a href='#page_node_view' id='" + item.text + "' class='page_node_pages_list_title'>" + item.text + "</a>");
          $("#pages_list").append(list_item);
    }
    if (item.class == "group") {
          var list_divider = $("<li data-role='list-divider' role='heading'></li>");
          list_divider.html(item.text);
          $("#pages_list").append(list_divider);
    }
});
```